# How can I implement a better filters for an api when handling multiple logic

Tags: javascript, mongodb, search

so i have an endpoint called `/search/sessions` this search has pretty complected logic so basically this session has multiple types lets say they are private, public, subscriber only , assigned to group,

in this endpoint it has the basic search options like text search and etc but they are not very important the hard part here is the logic lets assume the logic is

if the session is public it will display to all users , the subscriber only sessions will only display if the user is subscribed to this session. this happens only if he is logged in otherwise it wont show and if the session is private if the user is logged in and is a member he should see the private session,

lets talk about the group thing here lets assume we have two types of groups public and subscriber only

the sessions assigned to an private group should only show if the user is an member of a group this is obviously only if he's logged in as for subscriber only ones we should only show the session if the user is a subscriber of the group

but there's more weird logic imagine if i delete a session from a group still if user had already purchased the session show show even-tho the session is soft deleted from the database.

see these are just some type of logic i came up for the question what would be an `good` approach i can follow in these types of scenarios a place where i am suppose to change the data accoding to the user based on different conditions? actually curious what could be a good approach is there any opensource projects that implements an search like this based on the data ? that i can look in to ?

i tried to implement this in a way where first based on the user i fetch the relevent session ids for him basically if he's subscribed im fetching all the sub sessions for him and put it to an array

then if the user is in a private group i fetch sessions for that gropu and add them and finally using this id array to fetch the data

but this is inefficient

1. Im making a big ass array to store the data if the user has lot of sessions
2. i need to run lot of queries to fetch this id arrays and it's bad

i feel like there could be an way better solution for a scenario like this (im actually using mongodb btw)

Comment: This was a long story... could you synthetize this in a way we can make ourselves a clearer vision of your usecase ? Maybe a snippet of code would be a good start to illustrate. SO questions are expected to be minimal reproducible examples...